# Is proportional 3D weighted decimation on cubic objects possible?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, edit-mode, edges, vertex-weights

i´ve been thinking the last two days how to calculate this problem with blender, maybe im stupid and it´s simple. i need a specific decimation calculation to transform blue into green

img.A
[image]

img.B does this even make sense?
[image]

sorry but i have to say some introduction: I have a shape(blue, img.A) representing a baroque era chateau building. the extruding cubes in the middle and left and right are the so called risalits, while the two smaller parts connecting the three are called sidewings. the design Idea is the resulting 3dimensional proportional hierachy(key theme!)
The design transformation concept(img.B) is to collapse all vertical faces each in their weight median point so the polygon shape(green, img.A)) would result -. you see that the pointy edges extruding the new shape are supposed to be the equivalent of the 3dimensional risalit weight. so while the shape has less faces it still shows the proportional weight of the original but with pointy angles instead of cubes.

question is how to calculate this related transform? decimate mod. won´t work, it´s too lowpoly. smoothing doesn´t reduce the faces, and collapsing manually is too random..there has to be a calcualtion tool as basis, it´s essential for the concept to be digitally produced..that´s the problem :) thx in advance